# PostgreSQL query on a JSONB Array of Objects

Tags: sql, postgresql, nosql

I've a PostgreSQL  table with this complex structure :

```
"item": [{
        "field10",
        "field11",
        "field12": {
            "field20"
        },
        "field13": [{
                "field21": [{
                        "field30"
                    }
                ],
                "field22": [{
                        "field31"
                        "field32": {
                            "field40"
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    }]
```

And I've to make a query for filter until the **field40** many explication than I saw are for objects mor simple.
Can you explain me how can I do ?

**Edit :**

The example what I made i more simplest than reality. In reality the object is very very long. If I try to make a simple example with values, that's like that :

```
{
"uuid": "64fc7a55-be2d-41d8-99c1-d08fa5780731",
"item": [{
            "field10" : 2004,
            "field11" : false,
            "field12": {
                "field20" : "cc092aa1-6465-4526-9292-373344ed3e18",
                "field21" : "AMAZONE"
            },
            "field13": [{
                    "field22": [{
                            "field30" : "ee5bfd21-b2ce-453e-94a2-ef9c87002758",
                            "field31" : "MICROSOFTE"
                        },{
                            "field30" : "2eb39939-08b9-4456-9b5b-eff88f00bacb",
                            "field31" : "GOOGLEE"
                        }
                    ],
                    "field23": [{
                            "field32" : "e70bec99-689a-4c5d-ab81-e7601bc5b435",
                            "field33": {
                                "field40" : "a70ce09e-21ec-46cd-bfe6-591b84c0b328",
                                "field41" : "https://stackoverflow.com/"
                            }
                        },{
                            "field32" : "e70bec99-689a-4c5d-ab81-e7601bc5b435",
                            "field33": {
                                "field40" : "7bfa6882-2e65-4f96-b4a5-6aa0d148a95d",
                                "field41" : "https://gis.stackexchange.com/"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }]
},
{
"uuid": "f131864a-338e-4f2c-91b1-13950958bd62",
"item": [{
            "field10" : 2012,
            "field11" : false,
            "field12": {
                "field20" : "2b8176e4-c858-4159-b279-d852df77c63b",
                "field21" : "PIXABAYE"
            },
            "field13": [{
                    "field22": [{
                            "field30" : "9e70b3d8-8f3f-4ae1-ba64-86efa513bd28",
                            "field31" : "IOBEYAE"
                        },{
                            "field30" : "0150dba2-98de-4143-bd81-329b74874403",
                            "field31" : "PINTERESTE"
                        }
                    ],
                    "field23": [{
                            "field32" : "3ab19111-513a-47db-9fb5-52dc0a1e1c4d",
                            "field33": {
                                "field40" : "7be95726-6698-4bdd-8f6b-2595d1704a2a",
                                "field41" : "https://google.com/"
                            }
                        },{
                            "field32" : "7993aba5-f13f-4998-af7b-9b0b8aec8aa9",
                            "field33": {
                                "field40" : "4740dbcf-84c4-40ff-a633-9207e79cabf4",
                                "field41" : "https://yahoo.com/"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }]
}
```

In this example, my Postgres table have two columns, one with the primary key **uuid** and one with the object in jsonb **item**
And what I want, for example is to make a filter on my items where "field41" contains value "gis.stackexchange.com" for et in this example if I search "field41" = "https://yahoo.com/" the tuple with "uuid" = "uuid": "64fc7a55-be2d-41d8-99c1-d08fa5780731" will not be in the result

Comment: please rephrase and try to explain better , also provide desired output

Comment: Oh, I need ti make a filter on the fieldname field40 for example. "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE "(...) I saw many technics but not in this sublevel

Comment: this is not valid JSON. Is "item" an array or not? You mix both possibilities. "field20" and "field40" have no value. Or are they the values? What is the key? Or is "field32" an array? What do you want to achieve? Do you want to find "field40" in any nested JSON or do you want to get the value of "field40" in exactly this (corrected) structure?

Comment: Okay I edited my post sorry if it was not clear. So for your answer, item is a jsonb[] "field20" and "field40" have values, the key is the "uuid" field out of the item field, "field32" is not an array, it's a simple field. What I want for example is to make a filter on my items where "field41" contains value "https://gis.stackexchange.com/"  for et in this example if I search "field41" = "www.google.fr" the tuple with "uuid" = "uuid": "64fc7a55-be2d-41d8-99c1-d08fa5780731" will not be in the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With PostgreSQL v12 and better, you can use the jsonpath language to write such a query:

```
SELECT uuid
FROM jtab
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(
         item,
         '$[*].field13[*].field23[*].field33.field41 ? (@ == "https://yahoo.com/")'
      );
```

Comment: My Postgres version is 11.8 :-( But it's a good possibility !

Answer (score 2):

Your question suggests that you also need to accomplish a partial match on the URL in `"field41"`. This may be accomplished by enumerating each nested array with `jsonb_array_elements` and then using `WHERE ... LIKE ...` to filter records matching the desired domain name:

```sql
SELECT
   t.data->>'uuid' as uuid,
   jfield23->'field33'->>'field40' as field40,
   jfield23->'field33'->>'field41' as field41
FROM
   jtest t,
   jsonb_array_elements(t.data->'item') as jitem,
   jsonb_array_elements(jitem->'field13') as jfield13,
   jsonb_array_elements(jfield13->'field23') as jfield23
WHERE jfield23->'field33'->>'field41' LIKE '%' || 'yahoo.com' || '%'
```

I've included the the relevant `field40` and `field41` in the `SELECT` clause for illustration purposes.

See the full example on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0f4c2a8b7344637bc33663d6cdcd1424).